# What follows The Measure of the Magic?

Tags: suggested-order, shannara

I'm just finishing "[Legends of Shannara - The Measure Of The Magic](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10199908-the-measure-of-the-magic)" and I can't find what follows.

Can you advise me please?

Answer (score 3):

This one is actually slightly more complicated than you'd first think.

In strict [*in-universe Chronological*](http://www.goodreads.com/series/43574-shannara-chronological-order) terms, the next book is

> **[First King of Shannara (Shannara, #0)](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/92855.First_King_of_Shannara)**

Which is also Terry Brooks' [own recommendation](http://www.goodreads.com/series/99163-shannara---terry-s-suggested-reading-order-for-revisiting-readers) for ***revisiting readers***

---

In terms of **[strict publishing order](http://www.goodreads.com/series/99085-shannara-publication-order)**, the next book was

> [**Allanon's Quest (Paladins of Shannara, #1)**](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15743635-allanon-s-quest) (2012)

---

And Terry Brooks' own [**recommendation for *new readers***](http://www.goodreads.com/series/99160-shannara---terry-s-suggested-order-for-new-readers) (like yourself) is

> **[Wards of Faerie (The Dark Legacy of Shannara, #1)](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13265092-wards-of-faerie)**

Which would also be my own personal recommendation.

Comment: Having read about 80% of the series, I just recently decided to go through it chronologically. Gotta say, I love the series and I pray Chronicles is good.